# Get all new notifications when posted or removed on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am wondering if there is a way I can **get all the notifications when they are posted or removed** on **iOS using Swift 3**?

For example, the Android Wear iOS app has the ability to get all notifications and alert me when a new one arrived on my phone.

On Android, there is *Notification Listener Service* which I used to work with, but I would like to make it work for iOS too. However there seemed to be no resources online about that.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Any thanks would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I understand that ANCS can do that and I found that I do not have to write any code (Swift) for it. However, most of the examples I found can only send the notifications and nothing else.

For the Android Wear app, it can **connect to the BLE device within the app**, send not just **notifications**, but also **settings** to the device. How can I achieve this?

I forgot to mention that the device I am working on is an Arduino.

Comment: A Swift app can't do it, but a peripheral that uses ANCS can - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Paulw11 Please see update, thanks!

Comment: You can use Core Bluetooth to communicate between your app and a BLE peripheral.